# Disable ts errors in js project

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

So I have a `cra` app and I have set up a `.eslintrc.json` config with the help of `eslint --init`. Here's how it looks:

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off"
    }
}
```

I also have a `jsconfig.json` file. From what I understood, this is derived from the `tsconfig.json` config. Here's how mine looks:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./<path/to/src>",
    "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

From what I've read, if you set `checkJs` to `true` you get some features like auto-imports and from what I've tested, this is true and I like it. But what I don't like is having `ts` errors in my `js` files and getting recommended to add `ts-ignore` to the top of the file or to a certain line. What I can do is set the `checkJs` flag to `false` and those will go away, but so would some features like auto-import.

Can I keep the `checkJs` flag to `true` and still disable all `ts` errors in my `js` project? Is there a `eslint` rule for that? From what I saw, I would need to install a bunch of `ts eslint` packages and alter my `eslint` config, but this seems a bit off. Can this be done in a somewhat elegant way?

Comment: Do you want those features ("auto-import" and other IDE hints and inference) in your project or are you maintaining a library and want those features for your consumers?

Comment: Just in my project.

Comment: And what IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using VSCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on a monorepo project that uses TypeScript for type declaration files generation only (`.d.ts` files) based on JSDoc/TSDoc annotations. So, no real TypeScript code is used, only special comments.

This is the merged configuration for one of the packages:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "esModuleInterop": false,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "types": ["node", "mocha", "chai", "webpack", "tapable", "react"],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noEmit": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
        "declarationDir": "./types"
    }
}
```

We get full type checking and no errors that can't be solved by pure JavaScript (our TypeScript version is `^4.2.4`).

However, keep in mind that when you work with a type checker, generally you'll be forced to write your code in a stricter way (it is a pain, but it is worth it).

If you don't want to deal with TypeScript, because it may be hard to setup and maybe it is an overkill if you won't use all of its features, you can try [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app) (in my opinion, it should have been the standard for JavaScript type annotations, but the reality is far from that).

Also consider that it is possible that you will have to provide type annotations somehow (the only way to use TypeScript as a type-checking engine without actually writing TypeScript is by using JSDoc or TSDoc which is a variant of the former specifically designed for TypeScript).

Here is a [great article](https://medium.com/@trukrs/type-safe-javascript-with-jsdoc-7a2a63209b76) (there are many more, I recommend you to learn more about JavaScript type checking) (see [this](https://wojciechkrysiak.medium.com/typescript-jsdoc-better-docs-7c03b6ea04df) that specifically writes about JSDoc + TypeScript).

In our project, we do things like this:

```js
/** @type {Array<number>} */
const myNumbersArray = [];

myNumbersArray.push(0);   // OK
myNumbersArray.push('0'); // ERROR
```

Or

```js
/** @module core/modules/string-utils/split-by-words */

import {parse} from './parse.js';

/**
 * @description Splits passed string by words.
 * @param {string} str - Input string.
 * @returns {Array<string>} Results array.
 */
function splitByWords(str) {
    return parse(str).map((item) => item.content);
}

export {splitByWords};
```

Finally, there are many JSDoc ESLint libraries that you can use.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I don't have any problem with TS, I prefer it really over JS but for a certain small project I decided to use pure JS and I simply want the TS errors to disappear.

Comment: @Vivere if you wan't TS errors to disappear I would recommend you to disable/remove TS altogether. Using TS and adding `ts-ignore` comments in all files just to make your IDE 'smarter' seems a bit extreme. Using JSDoc could be a valid alternative because it is pure JS, but without the TS interpreter I think there will be no difference at IDE level.

Comment: I agree, I will look into JSDoc. I still hope for a solution whitin `jsconfig` though.